# Excel table with multiple arrays to list

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

I have the following table below (Input).
I looking for a method to get a list Output (see image).

[Table Input/Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzuvi.png)

Comment: Show us what you tried?

Comment: The example does not define  problem well. In your example, you show only 3 rows of output for 30/07/2017, so the implication is that multiple occurrences of an item for a date should generate only one output row rather than a row for each occurrence (as the solution by @Mrig has assumed). It would have, perhaps been clearer if you had included a full output table in your example rather than truncating it to the first 2 input columns. You have not tagged your question with `VBA` so are you looking for a solution which avoids VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should help:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, currRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")      'change Sheet1 to your working sheet

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row in column A
        lastCol = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get last column in row 3
        currRow = 3     'output will be displayed from row 3

        For rowIndex = 4 To lastRow 'loop through all rows in input starting with row 4
            For colIndex = 2 To lastCol   'loop trough all columns in input starting form column 2
                arr = Split(.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex).Value, ",") 'put comma separated value of a cell in array
                For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'loop through array item
                    .Range("I" & currRow).Value = .Range("A" & rowIndex).Value 'display name
                    .Range("J" & currRow).Value = .Cells(3, colIndex) 'display date
                    .Range("K" & currRow).Value = Trim(arr(i)) 'display cell value
                    currRow = currRow + 1       'increment crrRow value by 1
                Next i
            Next colIndex
        Next rowIndex
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

See image for reference.

[image]